# Got a failed log-in attempt message. Is it possible someone tried to enter my PC remotely?

Tags: passwords

A while ago my PC kind of got frozen. The mouse was moving but I couldn't open other windows and I couldn't open the task manager pressing ctrl-shift-Esc. After a couple of minutes I just pressed the power button and forced it to restart. Before entering my laptop's password I got a message that because of failed log-in attempts I had to write something (to prove I'm not a robot i belive). The weird thing is that I hadn't failed to put in my password yet. Is it possible that someone was trying to enter my PC remotely? Note that i just bought this PC 4 weeks ago and haven't downloaded anything from shady websites nor have I opened suspicious e-mails. Is it possible to get access to other PC's without malware? I belive it was just a bug but I wanted to know what you guys think.

Comment: What operating system is running on your PC?

Comment: I'm using windows